# return permanent pointer to array after saving delimited text file to it

Tags: c, arrays, scanf

i am trying to store a text file looking like this:

```
Headphones-750, TV-1500, Keyboard-1200, Tablet-80, Speakers-400, DVD-250, Streamer-550, Mouse-50;
```

into an array of type def:

```
    typedef struct item{
        char* name;
        int price;
    }item;

    typedef struct item{
        char* name;
        int product_code;
        int price;
    }item;



item *getProducts(){
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("machinedata.txt", "r");

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error while opening the file.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    static item products[8];
    int row = 0;

    while (fscanf(fp,"%50[^-],%10[^,]",products[row].name,products[row].price) ){
        products[row].product_code = row;
        row++;
    }

    return products;
}
```

but it wont work. how can i create this array of `typedef item` and return a pointer to array which i will be able to manipulate/print from other functions and main() in particular.

i am coding in C and looking for a C guidance please

Comment: do not typedef a struct.  The result is cluttered code, misunderstandings, and clutters the compiler name space.

Comment: You have not allocated any memory for `products[row].name` and so are passing an uninitialised pointer to `fscanf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has one typedef for `item`.
`item products[8];` is in main where it can be passed to other functions.
the `name` member of `items` is a pointer. Memory needs to be allocated to it to store the string from the file.
The format string `" %50[^-]-%d%*c"` will skip leading whitespace, scan up to 50 characters that are not '-', scan a '-', scan an integer and scan and discard a character following the integer.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct item{
    char* name;
    int product_code;
    int price;
}item;

int getProducts ( item prods[], int size);

int main ( ) {
    int read = 0;
    int each = 0;
    item products[8];

    read = getProducts ( products, sizeof ( products) / sizeof ( products[0]));
    for ( each = 0; each < read; each++) {
        printf ( "%s %d %d\n", products[each].name, products[each].price, products[each].product_code);
    }
    for ( each = 0; each < read; each++) {
        free ( products[each].name);//release memory
    }
    return 0;
}

int getProducts ( item prods[], int size) {
    char name[51] = {0};
    int row = 0;

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("machinedata.txt", "r");

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error while opening the file.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while ((fscanf(fp," %50[^-]-%d%*c",name,&prods[row].price))==2){
        prods[row].name = malloc ( strlen ( name) + 1);//allocate memory for name
        if ( prods[row].name == NULL) {
            printf ( "Malloc failed\n");
            break;
        }
        strcpy ( prods[row].name, name);//copy name into structure
        prods[row].product_code = row;
        row++;
        if ( row >= size) {
            break;
        }
    }

    return row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there are a few problems with the code.

```
1) it does not compile.
    it needs #include <stdio.h>
    and #include <stdlib.h>
2) the struct 'item' is defined two different ways.
    suggest remove the typdef that does not have the product code field
3) the second input conversion identifier in the format string
   in the fscanf() statement is expecting a char* parameter,
   but the parameter is int*.
```

So, how can it be said to not work, when it doesn't even compile?

Suggest compiling with all warnings enabled,  (for gcc '-Wall -Wextra -pedantic')   fix the warnings, then re-post the code

Answer (score 0):

You have multiply defined `typedef struct item`. The compiler should issue report an error.

In `fscanf(...,products[row].price)` you should pass the address of the int, not its value, so write `&products[row].price)`.

It is adviced to test that no more rows are read then 8, for example `if (row<8 && fscanf(....))`.